# Instance Variable in Ruby Resetting as Nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

My instance variables gets turned back to nil, even though it was set in a separate function that is called.

I've tried printing out before and after values for the instance variable, and have seen where it turns to nil. It's quite puzzling though. Attaching an example (https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickPresentKeyboard) also below:

```
class Test
  def process 
    return if a.nil? && b.nil?
    puts @some
  end

  def a
    @some = nil
    return true
  end

  def b
    @some = "abc"
    return false
  end

end

class Test2
  def process 
    return if c.nil?
    puts @hello
  end

  def c
    @hello = "hello"
    return true
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.process

t2 = Test2.new
t2.process
```

In the Test class, I expect *@some* to print "abc" since it is set during the "b" function. However, it prints nil.

In the Test2 class, I expect *@hello* to print "hello" and it certainly does.

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby issue, so you shouldn't have a Rails tag.

Comment: I don't think `Test2` is needed, as the question is perfectly clear without it. If anything it muddles the question. Note that there is no need for the keyword `return` in the last lines of `a` and `b`. If removed, `true` and `false` would be last expressions evaluated in each method, and therefore would be the respective return values. `return` does no harm, but the practice is to not use it when it is superfluous.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for feedback on composition of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example your method `b` never executes: `&&` returns its first argument if it is falsy. Otherwise, it evaluates and returns its second argument. Since `a.nil?` evaluates to `false` the second expression never gets called.

Try this:

```
  def process 
    return if a && b
    puts @some
  end
```

Comment: You might be more specific: `a` returns `true` and `true.nil? #=> false`.